# How to modify textbox value in new thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I've got this Sub:

```
Public Sub obtenerValorDeFichero()
    Dim ruta As String
    ruta = "file.txt"
    Dim myFile As New FileInfo(ruta)
    Dim sizeInBytes As Long = myFile.Length
    While (Convert.ToInt32(sizeInBytes.ToString) < 4)
        myFile.Refresh()
        sizeInBytes = myFile.Length
    End While
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    Me.TextBox3.Text = File.ReadAllText(ruta).Trim
End Sub
```

And I'm calling it in the New code by this way:

```
Dim myThread As System.Threading.Thread
myThread = New System.Threading.Thread(Sub() obtenerValorDeFichero())
myThread.Start()
```

But it crashes when try's to change the Me.Textbox3.Text value, how can i do it?

Comment: What is the error you get when it crashes?

Comment: First: add a `try/catch` statement and print in a message box the error: `MsgBox(ex.Message)`

Comment: Invalid operation exception, Control 'textBox3' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Comment: @marcss yup, a thread cannot update the GUI on the main thread

Comment: You don't modify controls on threads other than the one they were created on.

Comment: and how can i do it? i need to modify in the form

Comment: Try to use the [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) instead

Comment: For the record, a `Long` is a number just like an `Integer` (only it has a higher maximum value); you don't need to convert it. You can replace this: `While (Convert.ToInt32(sizeInBytes.ToString) < 4)` with this: `While sizeInBytes < 4`.

Answer (score 1):

I use this approach to update TextBox from a thread other than the thread it was created.

```
Private Delegate Sub SetTextBoxDelegate(ByVal TB As TextBox, ByVal txt As String)

Private Sub SetTextBoxWithInvoke(ByVal TB As TextBox, ByVal txt As String)
    If TB.InvokeRequired Then
        TB.Invoke(New SetTextBoxDelegate(AddressOf SetTextBoxWithInvoke), New Object() {TB, txt})
    Else
        TB.Text = txt
    End If
End Sub
```

Then in `obtenerValorDeFichero()` you can replace

```
Me.TextBox3.Text = File.ReadAllText(ruta).Trim
```

With

```
SetTextBoxWithInvoke(Me.TextBox3, File.ReadAllText(ruta).Trim)
```

Regards.